# Calculate subset mean using criteria and saved in a new date frame

Tags: r, subset, mean

I have a set of data generated by different participants who score different visual impairments by giving Technical Quality score between 1-5.

Data sample is below where Column Participant is text (different IDs), column Impairment is text (9 distinctive types), column TechnicalQuality is numeric (1-5).

```
Participant <- c("A001", "A001", "A001", "A002", "A002", "A003", "B001", "B002")
impairment <- c ("H0", "H1", "H3", "H2",  "H4", "H2", "H3", "H0")
TechnicalQuality <- c(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1)
Exp_1<- data.frame(Participant = Participant, impairment = impairment,
                 TechnicalQuality = TechnicalQuality
```

I am hoping to create a new data frame P_TQ_Mean that includes mean TechnicalQuality for each type of impairment per Participant and I used following Code:

```
 P_TQ_Mean<-c()
 for (i in unique(Exp_1$Participant)){
 d<-subset(Exp_1, Exp_1$Participant ==i)
 c <- aggregate(d$TechnicalQuality, list(d$impairment), mean)
 P_TQ_Mean = rbind(P_TQ_Mean,c)
 }
```

The generated P_TQ_Mean is:

```
  Group.1 x
1      H0 1
2      H1 2
3      H3 4
4      H2 3
5      H4 5
6      H2 4
7      H3 3
8      H0 1
```

This shows "A001" has three mean for H0, H1 and H3 respectively, and so on for other Participants.

Is there any way to add one column to indicate the Participant ID for each mean per impairment, as well as label the first two column properly? For example, I need label Group.1 as "impairment" and x as "Participant" for further process.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a R question. Tag this with the name of the software you are using; otherwise it will disappear into the abyss.

Comment: Try `aggregate(TechnicalQuality ~ impairment + Participant, Exp_1, mean)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need in a `for` loop. `aggregate` can handle several aggregators, try

```
aggregate(TechnicalQuality ~ impairment + Participant, Exp_1, mean)
#   impairment Participant TechnicalQuality
# 1         H0        A001                1
# 2         H1        A001                2
# 3         H3        A001                4
# 4         H2        A002                3
# 5         H4        A002                5
# 6         H2        A003                4
# 7         H3        B001                3
# 8         H0        B002                1
```

Or some more efficient options

```
# install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
setDT(Exp_1)[, list(TechnicalQuality = sum(TechnicalQuality)), by = list(Participant, impairment)]
#    Participant impairment TechnicalQuality
# 1:        A001         H0                1
# 2:        A001         H1                2
# 3:        A001         H3                4
# 4:        A002         H2                3
# 5:        A002         H4                5
# 6:        A003         H2                4
# 7:        B001         H3                3
# 8:        B002         H0                1
```

Or

```
# install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
Exp_1 %>%
  group_by(Participant, impairment) %>%
  summarise(mean(TechnicalQuality))
# Source: local data table [8 x 3]
# Groups: Participant
# 
#   Participant impairment mean(TechnicalQuality)
# 1        A001         H0                      1
# 2        A001         H1                      2
# 3        A001         H3                      4
# 4        A002         H2                      3
# 5        A002         H4                      5
# 6        A003         H2                      4
# 7        B001         H3                      3
# 8        B002         H0                      1
```

Comment: Absolutely stunning, never thought the solution could be so elegant! Thank you very much! I don't have enough Reputation to vote up yet, but will once I have!

Comment: NP, glad I could help.